# minimization of square plus distance metric

Tags: calculus, optimization

In [today's advent of code](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/7) the second part (hidden) asks you to find (via programming, but who has time for that when we can do linear solutions with math) a point that essentially minimize $a$ for the $\sum_i (y_i -a)^2+\sum_i \lvert y_i -a\rvert$ metric. The first expression would be the average and the second the median, but I get nastiness when I tried to minimize their sum. Is there a name for this? Is there even a unique solution in general (I think no?) Can you help me characterize it?

Comment: using the normal approach I get something like $a=\langle y\rangle -\frac{1}{2n}\sum_i \mathrm{sgn}(a-y_i)$ which I can't solve, isn't clear has unique solutions, and isn't clear I haven't eliminated any weird cusp solutions

Comment: Indeed it eliminates a weird cusp solution a y={1,2,4,10}; can it be rigorously proven the minimum is within 0.5 of the average still though?

Comment: yes it can be proven with partitioning

Answer (score 1):

It has a unique solution, because the function is convex (it is a sum of convex functions with positive coefficients). However, the solution has to be found numerically, which is in one-dimension easy, for example by the golden search method.

Comment: I've been told the sgn relation in the comment allows a bound to be proven by substituting |y-a| for sqrt((y-a)^2+c), but I have doubts this is valid instead of the piecewise solution. Can't the lack of differentiability not be solved like this, even for deriving bounds? In this case the bounds happen to be correct, but surely it's wrong

Comment: I do not understand your comment, can you be more specific? Do you search for bounds for the solution? Surely $\min_i y_i \le a \le \max_i y_i$, but possibly better bounds can be found. The solution is maybe located between average and median.